# Connecting to NFS Share with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, nfs

I'm using Windows 10 Pro and am trying to connect to my Linux NFS Share. I have enabled NFS Services, but when executing the mount command I get the following error message (in German):

```
FEHLER - nicht unterstützte Version von Windows
```

(in English)

```
ERROR - Windows version is not supported
```

Anyone knows fixes, or other ways to connect to NFS?

Comment: What mount command are you using? This would be helpful to know for anyone that may try to assist you with the problem. The error is good to know in English especially, but knowing what you're running command line wise would be helpful as well. You might also confirm you are running command prompt elevated as administrator and that you've already rebooted your machine since enabling the NFS features just in case it's something as simple as that to resolve.

Comment: NFS support seems to work fine on my copy of Windows 10 Pro. I was able to mount a share I have on a FreeBSD server with no problem. The 'ver' command says my version is Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393].